# Help with if/else statement

Tags: php, magento-1, if

```
 <div class="stock">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I have this piece of code right here currently displaying in stock or out of stock on my store. I want to add a 3rd else to display a custom stock status. How can i do that? Can anyone show me?

This would be my third option:

```
<p><?php $_product->getAttributeText('custom_status');?></p>
```

or at least hide the stock status when a custom status  exists.

Comment: your custom_status is qty number? some more detail about custom_status.

Comment: in what case do you want to display a custom status? Of it's set, or if the product is not salable?

Comment: No the custom stock status is text. example: "Please call to order"

Comment: Well I would like to display it when I select the custom status from the drop down. I added an attribute so if the attribute is selected then only the custom status should show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want something like that

```
<div class="stock">
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && !$_product->getCustomStatus()): ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></p>
    <?php elseif($_product->getCustomStatus()): ?>
        <p><?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('custom_status');?></p> 
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<div class="stock">
    <?php if ($_product->getCustomStatus()) : ?>
        <p class="prodstock-custom"><?php echo $_product->getCustomStatus(); ?></p>
    <?php elseif($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="prodstock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```